# Why is Swift MapKit constantly making accessibility updates?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, mapkit

I have a standard MapView however whenever I pan around the map the following is printed to the console:

```
2020-07-07 15:35:16.809318-0700 Rage[81310:4345816] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2020-07-07 15:35:16.811355-0700 Rage[81310:4345816] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
```

After a few pans on the map view my console ends up looking like this:

```
2020-07-07 15:37:17.814988-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2020-07-07 15:37:17.817476-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
2020-07-07 15:37:18.754827-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2020-07-07 15:37:18.758369-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
2020-07-07 15:37:20.425499-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2020-07-07 15:37:20.427592-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
2020-07-07 15:37:21.895455-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2020-07-07 15:37:21.898904-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
2020-07-07 15:37:22.195264-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2020-07-07 15:37:22.199350-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
2020-07-07 15:39:29.344402-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2020-07-07 15:39:29.348122-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
2020-07-07 15:39:30.456435-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2020-07-07 15:39:30.460018-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
2020-07-07 15:39:31.091947-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2020-07-07 15:39:31.095617-0700 Rage[81362:4348665] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
```

Other than it polluting the console it does not seem to have any adverse effects on performance. Does anyone know why this keeps showing up on my console?

Comment: I'm wondering this myself. Did you figure it out?